# I'm trying to remove a child element in list

Tags: spring, hibernate

Book:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@JoinColumn(name = "LIBRARY_ID", nullable = false)
private Library library;
```

Library:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "library")
private List<Book> books;
```

Service:

```
public void deleteBook(Long book_id) {
    Book book = bookDao.get(book_id);
    Library library = libraryDao.get(book.getLibrary().getId());

    library.getBooks().remove(book);    
    book.setLibrary(null);

}
```

**deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.quangdat.entities.Book#1]**

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of equality check. provide an equal method for your `Book` class and check if it's working correctly or not.